# batch file iterating sorted pairs slow

Tags: batch-file

I am normally not using batch so please forgive me if this is obvious. I would prefer not to use Make on this one but i will if i have to. But let's take a look if we can fix this instead:

It goes through the (only) 137 .c's in a folder compares their modification-date with their .o's and recompiles if newer.

The inner for-loop is only to get the name of the newer file into the `%%I` variable, so it should not have quadratic run-time, but **the problem is** that it is way too slow. It takes 10 seconds even if nothing needs recompiling, it is just looping and sorting each pair.

```
for %%f in (*.c) do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('dir /b /OD %%~nf.o %%~nf.c ^| more +1') do (
        if %%I == %%~nI.c ( 
            REM recompile the file
        ) else (
            REM skip it
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But obviously you start 137 `dir /b` rounds for each each of your 137 c-files.
And then you start a new cmd context with the pipe.

I suppose it's not the best way to compare the file times.
You could sort the complete directory, that should be faster.
First I sort all c and o files by date and then I create a variable (`cfile_<filename>`) for each c-file.
And for each o-file I clear the variable.
After all files the remaining `cfile_` variables used to recompile the related c-files.

The redirection `2>nul` is only to avoid an error message for the case, when no variables begins with `cfile_`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem remove all old variables
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('set cfile_ 2^>nul') do set "%%a="

For /F "Delims=" %%I In ('dir /b /OD *.o *.c') do (
  if %%~xI==.o (
    set "cfile_%%~nI="
  ) ELSE (
    set cfile_%%~nI=1
  )
)

for /F "tokens=2* delims=_" %%c in ('set cfile_ 2^>nul') do echo Recompile %%c
```

Comment: This is definitely the approach i was hoping for, but at the moment it always takes the `else` path, as if I were not modifying the .c file at all. Does this depend on a certain version of windows/cmd.exe?

Comment: @eznme No, it should work with XP, W7 and also W8. But you could add `echo %%~xI,%%I` just before the `if %%~xI ...` to see what extensions/files are found. Or do you use special characters in your filenames like spaces, exclamation marks or something else?

Comment: only a-to-z and a single dot. I already added the echo to check if also the order of checking was correct, and in fact the ordering shows that the main.c which i am changing the whole time is listed last, so far so good.

Comment: I wonder if the clearing of the variables is working: if i echo the %%a then it includes the "=1" so my guess is that it is not clearing cfile_asdf.c but instead setting "cfile_asdf.c=1="

Comment: I don't understand `a-to-z`, you should only see `.o` or `.c`, do you see also `main.o`? I changed the logic, so it also recompiles, when there isn't a matching `.o` file

Comment: no the "a-to-z and a single dot" was the answer to your question which filenames i am using. (If I use your %%~xI then there's only .o and .c)

Comment: It works! At the same time I made a version in which I sort newest-first (/O-D) and make the .o files set variables and make .c files compile if the matching variable was not-yet set (i.e. if the matching .o file was not yet seen). But I think I will prefer your version!